# how to consume post api in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I consumed a get api by creating a base service like that:

```cs
public class BaseService<T> where T : class
    {
        private string baseUrl = "http://192.168.43.137:45455/api";
        public IEnumerable<T> GetRequest(string uri)
        {
            baseUrl += uri;
            var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            var response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string json = response.Content;

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(json);
            }
            return default;
        }
```

and a userService like this:

```cs
 public class UserServices     {

        public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers() 
        {
            var requestService = new BaseService<User>();
            return requestService.GetRequest("/Users");

        }
```

It worked fine for the get but I don't know how to consume the post api like this

Comment: why are you posting **another** question about this?  there are thousands of existing questions about doing a POST in C#.  https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2523+httpclient+post+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You can check the microsoft document "**Consume a RESTful web service**":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

It shows you how to deal with the different kinds of requests, and there is a sample link in the bottom which you can refer to.